# Would a Dragon be able to use the Fleet of Foot feat while flying?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, feats, dragons, flight, charge

Fleet of Foot from Complete Warrior: Would a Dragon be able to use the Fleet of Foot feat while flying? The feat states: "When running or **charging**..

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Comment: Does your question boils down to "can a monster run or charge while flying?"

Answer (score 5):

## Yes

A dragon or other creature that's flying can typically realize the benefit of the feat **Fleet of Foot** (*Complete Warrior* 99). The feat's benefit says

> When running or charging, you can make a single direction change of 90 degrees or less. You can’t use this feat in medium or heavy armor, or if you’re carrying a medium or heavier load. If you are charging, you must move in a straight line for 10 feet (2 squares) after the turn to maintain the charge.

The *Monster Manual* on [Movement Modes](http://dndsrd.net/monsterTypes.html#movement-modes) says, "A creature can use the run action while flying, provided it flies in a straight line" (312), and it says this in addition to adding a chargelike attack dive to a flying creature's ability to make normally the special attack [charge](http://dndsrd.net/specialAttacks.html#charge) (*Player's Handbook* 154–5). (The Rules of the Game Web column ["All about Movement (Part Five)"](http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/rg/20040706a) describes possible changes to a flying creature's normal charge.) (Also, the contradictions between the *Player's Handbook* and the *Monster Manual* on the amount a creature can carry and still fly is covered by [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/147292/8610).)

Comment: [Because of their publication dates](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/56771/8610) the feat Fleet of Foot from *Complete Warrior* (Dec. 2003) is superseded by the feat Fleet of Foot from *Player's Guide to Faerûn* (March 2004). However, this is silly, and your campaign should totally allow both feats.

Comment: Oh, we just had this discussion over in another question about the actual total number of feats. ^^